# Use Node envs in json file

Tags: json, node.js, environment-variables

Im using dotenv to declare my envs and then I import the m to the main file but I have a json file which needs the proccess.env but I don't want to hard code the API keys

Is there a way to the envs to the json file without hard coding them ?

from this

```
  {
        "accessKeyId": "ACCESS_KEY",
        "secretAccessKey": "SECRET_KEY",
        "region": "us-east-1"
   }
```

to this

```
 {
        "accessKeyId": proccess.env.ACCESS_KEY,
        "secretAccessKey": "SECRET_KEY",
        "region": "us-east-1"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a JSON file you can create a `javascript` file and export the `json` object

```
module.exports =  {
    "accessKeyId": process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    "secretAccessKey": process.env.SECRET_KEY,,
    "region": "us-east-1"
}
```

in your code you can directly require this file.